# android how to send image to mysql db

Tags: php, android, mysql, bitmap

I am trying to send in andoid a bitmap to a mysql db.This is what I have done so far:

convert my bitmap with:

```
    public static String bitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return temp;}
```

I put this string to the post parameters and send it to the database...like:
httppost.setEntity(createPostParam(parameters));

on server side with php, I decode my string with:

```
base64_decode($value);
```

and finally store it in a blob.

When I store a image manually in the database, it will show me on the application.
just by sending from the app, it shows me a black image, but I can see that binary data is stored and available in the database and the application...

Can anybody help me out here? Could it be a problem with UTF-8?

Comment: You should start checking $value for the same base64 string as sent by your app. Now did you?

Comment: this is what is stored in the db: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJkAAADMCAYAAABgHwH+AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU
eJycvNuvJUuS5vUzM3ePiLX23pkn81yqTnVdu3q6q7sZZhhGCCHBCyDxD8wb/yAP8MYrMPDWoEaD
mK6eahVdqurqU+ecvO3LWhHh7mY8eOQuRqKFmC2lcufOtdeKCDc3++z7PnP5F//VfxyCEexYV8RO
rG2nyRPZglYBzZidSWZslwtdKtI35qUQEYRWkhS6zvzZf/Ff8yo/cXr3N2R2sk5IONkMj5XtKtT2
xJRuiQjENzAlXHh8fGS/X2lReL+t/PrDB5xApfKDH/yEr//+ax7XDbWGiHC5XrFpptVKq87di5kk....................

Comment: this is the string from the bitmap:

Comment: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJkAAADMCAYAAABgHwH+AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU...

Comment: it doesn't looks realy binary...but it should, because i use base64_decode(), i have no idea what i should change...it seems like the base64_decode function not working...

Comment: Sorry. We are not interested for what is stored in the db. You had a bitmap which you base64 encoded in a string. Then you sent that string and received in $value by php. I asked you to compare the sent string (in the app) with the received string in $value. You should tell if they have the same length and are equal.